# Shopping cart in codeigniter not working properly

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am new to codeigniter framework I have created one cart using codeigniter library. The problem of the cart is that when I want to remove the product from the cart then the product is not removing immediately from the cart rather i have to press F5 i.e refresh the whole page then it appears correctly does there is any problem with the codeigniter or I am doing any wrong logic.

Following is the cart controller to remove the product from my cart

```
  function remove($rowid) {
    $data = array(
        'rowid' => $rowid,
        'qty' => 0
    );
    $this->cart->update($data);
    $this->load->view('cart');  
}
```

Following is the link to remove the product from the cart

```
 <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>cart/remove/<?php echo trim($items['rowid']); ?>">remove</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter Shopping Cart Strange Behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372105/codeigniter-shopping-cart-strange-behaviour)

Answer (score 0):

try this. use redirect to redirect page

```
function remove($rowid) {
    $data = array(
        'rowid' => $rowid,
        'qty' => 0
    );
  $this->cart->update($data);

    redirect(site_url('cart'), 'refresh');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this may works for you: 
you should redirect after update your database do not us $this->load

**your controller**

```
class Cart extends CI_Controller
  function index(){
    $this->load->view('cart');  
  }
  function remove($rowid) {
    $data = array(
        'rowid' => $rowid,
        'qty' => 0
    );
    $this->cart->update($data);
    redirect('cart', 'refresh');
  }
}
```

**your view:**

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>cart/remove/<?php echo trim($items['rowid']); ?>">remove</a>
```

Comment: autoload url library in your structure like config/autoload.php

Comment: The redirection is not working properly with it so i have to use loading view

Comment: you can try to delete via ajax is simple without refreshing a page.

Answer (score 0):

you are not sending $data to your view. Try to change in your controller

```
 $this->load->view('cart',$data);
```